# Can't log out Xamarin account in Visual Studio

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

Latest XamarinVS, tried both 2015 and "15" Preview, I click log out in Tools/Xamarin Account... but nothing happens.
How can I log out to login back, because I've been having an unhandled activation error and I read logout/login is the workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must first delete mandroid.exe & mtouch.exe from this address "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin" and then log out. :)

Answer (score 2):

delete license files from Program Data. Maybe you installed xamarin older version before. 
C:\ProgramData
delete 2 folder Mono for Android, MonoTouch.