# In Visual Studio 2017 on PC, Where logout of expired Xamarin Account?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 on PC, to develop both for Android and for iOS (remote to Mac).

When I start VS for the day, and open the solution, the first time I try to build the iOS project, I get a message that my Xamarin Account is expired, but I can still use VS Pro features. It seems harmless; but I have to click on it, then start the build again. An annoyance to do this every day.

According to [Can't log out Xamarin account in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36655270/199364), there used to be a menu item `Tools/Xamarin Account..`, but this seems to be removed in VS 2017 (or in the current Xamarin addin).

Where do I logout of this Xamarin Account?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `Tools/Xamarin Account..` menu item was removed because a Xamarin account now is *only* needed to access Xamarin Components store (your Microsoft account login to Visual Studio gives you access to Xamarin building and deploying).

So, the answer is found on `Components` item in any Xamarin project, in Solution Explorer:
rt-click on `Components`, select `LogOut...`.

---

If you later need to "login", you can do so via `Edit Components...` or `Get More Components...` in that same menu.